# How to cut the result of ps command

Tags: ps

Could you please explain this command? 
and what does 48 means ?
ps -laef | cut -c 48- | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Run it per partes and you see how the output changes. (it should be safe in this case)

`ps -laef`

`ps -laef | cut -c 48-`

`ps -laef | cut -c 48- | sort`

`ps -laef | cut -c 48- | sort | uniq -c`

`ps -laef | cut -c 48- | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

See the [man page of cut(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) for explanation of what parameters do.

```
-c, --characters=LIST 
    select only these characters

N- 
    from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line
```